# Magmi import description with double quote, show up on magento web with "/"

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a product with " in the description field.

2 3/4" x 17 1/2" Clip-On Hand File Board,Part Number,0008.0159

After using magmi import, it shows up on the web site as

2 3/4\" x 17 1/2\" Clip-On Hand File Board,Part Number,0008.0159

how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First- I have yet to get magmi to import correctly 
But I would assume it would be the standard double quote "" 
So you would have it as 3 quotes""" because your quoting a quote sign.

Answer (score 0):

2 3/4" x 17 1/2" Clip-On Hand File Board,Part Number,0008.0159

MAKE THIS

"2 3/4"" x 17 1/2"" Clip-On Hand File Board","Part Number","0008.0159"